# Stop macOS from creating/storing previous versions of a document

Tags: macos, file, history, versions

macOS creates a history or previous version of each any every document/file I edit and this not only happens across the os but also happens across every mac apps.

These version files takes up huge chunks of unnecessary storage so how can I stop macOS from making this histories/previous document versions and storing it on your HDD.

I don't have Time Machine backup enabled and it still stores and saves the previous versions of a file!

Comment: Note that versions do not take up disk space as the space will be reclaimed automatically by macOS as required.

Comment: @grgarside Really? then why on using a cache/history cleaner app for Sketch App it showed me that Sketch Version Files are taking up 1.5 GB

Comment: Most of those apps don't properly understand the filesystem and incorrectly count transient files, or count them on purpose but make a note somewhere that they do so. You shouldn't worry about the space, let macOS handle the storage requirements and enjoy the versions feature without worrying about the underlying implementation. Disk Utility, Finder and System Information will show this space grouped as Purgeable, meaning that if anything needs the space it will remove purgeable content such as versions to fit.

Comment: @grgarside Hmmm, But when the OS loads I mean boot-up don't these purgeable files put loads on the system and increase startup times

Comment: Nope, they're just files on the system like any other, accessed by the OS when necessary.

Comment: @grgarside One more thing how can I stop MacOS from creating and storing User and system Log files?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/157154/37797

Comment: @grgarside so now if I edit the above said file and now if I open logs app I won't see any logs, will I?